# How to check wether a control has been loaded?

Tags: .net, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a UserControl, which has a `SetCameraCount` method that can be used before and/or after the control is actually displayed.

If `SetCameraCount` is used **before** the control is displayed, then nothing should be done except to set `cameraCount` so the control uses it when it loads the first time.

If `SetCameraCount` is used is set **after** the control is loaded, then the control should updates the same way as when it was loaded the first time using the new `cameraCount` value.

To achieve this, I am using `_IsLoaded` as a bool to check wether the UserControl is loaded or not.

```
bool _IsLoaded;

int cameraCount;

public void SetCameraCount(int cameraCount)
{
    if (this.cameraCount != cameraCount)
    {
        this.cameraCount = cameraCount;

        if (_IsLoaded)
            buildMenu();
    }
}

void CamMultiple_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buildMenu();
    _IsLoaded = true;
}

void buildMenu()
{
    // this method will absolutely fail if the control is not loaded
    // ...
}
```

I am using this pattern very often.

Although it works fine, I wonder if I could replace the `_IsLoaded` bool by some property already implemented in Windows Forms. For now I did not find anything. Do you know about such a property?

Comment: IsHandleCreated would be a match.  No good reason for a "build menu" operation to fail btw.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. buildMenu is specific internal boilerplate that requires a constructed control, not the one in winforms.

Comment: Well, that's why UserControl has a constructor.  If you need to create an object of another class then do so in your constructor, avoid using events that run later at an unpredictable time.

Comment: IsHandleCreated is ok. Also seems the Created property. Would you please like to change your comment to an answer so I can credit you? Thanks.

Comment: I'll skip, I don't particularly care for the idea that this is necessary at all.

Comment: As you wish, I will self answer this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UserControl property value change which impacts other visual elements needs to handle two scenarios :

- **before** the control is visible: The constrol is constructed, but not yet added to a controls collection. The Load event has not been yet fired, and some visual elements the control contains are not ready yet. That's why the property value has to be stored somewhere and be used as the control Load event is fired.
- **after** the control is loaded: the visual elements that the controls uses are ready. A property value change can be applied properly.

That's why I use the pattern described in the question.

As commented by Hans Passant, the property `IsHandleCreated` gets true when the control is loaded. The Created property seems to work also, but I need to test it further.